# AVX alternative of AVX2's vector shift?

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators, bit-shift, avx, avx2

In AVX2 we have `_mm256_srlv_epi32(a, b)` and `_mm256_sllv_epi32(a, b)` for shifting a set of 8 values in 'a' by the 8 values in 'b'. Is there an efficient alternative using AVX so that I can stay in AVX and not have to spit out to scalar code?

Comment: you mean `_mm256_srlv_epi32`? because I found no intrinsic called `_mm256_srlv`

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Yes, I omitted the type but I just edited it in.

Comment: You're out of luck I'm afraid - AVX is pretty much all floating point instructions. No need to use scalar code though, you can probably just use SSE instructions on each half of the AVX vector.

Comment: @PaulR: variable-shift is new in AVX2, though.  There's no 128b variable-shift.  I'm in the middle of an answer about a bad idea with a shift for each different count and immediate-blend.  Unpacking the shift count for `psrld xmm,xmm` is nasty, too, though.

Comment: @PeterCordes: yes, it's non-trivial with SSE, but I'm sure it must still be possible to do it more efficiently than dropping down to scalar code. This would probably make an interesting SO question in its own right (assuming it hasn't already been asked!).

Comment: @PaulR: Have a look at what I came up with.  It takes 4 insns to isolate the shift counts, plush 4 shifts, plus 3 more blends.  If I had to avoid SSE4.1 pblendw and blendps, things would be significantly worse.

Comment: @PeterCordes: very nice - it would be interesting to benchmark scalar code versus your SSE implementation versus AVX2 - I suspect your SSE code will be somewhere around the middle of the two extremes.

Comment: @PaulR: I just added uop counts for my version and for likely scalar implementations, like you'd probably see in compiler output.  Scalar is just horrible for fully-variable, because `shr r32, cl` is 3 uops.  AVX2 just absolutely destroys even my SSE version, esp. on Skylake where `vpsrlvd` is 1 uop (instead of 3 on Haswell).  On Skylake, my AVX1 version should be ~15x slower.  Or ~30x if you account for the fact that it's doing 8 elements per insn while my unpack / recombine is only doing 4 elements.  My AVX1 version should be a bit faster on SnB than on Haswell, BTW (shuffle throughput).

Comment: @PeterCordes: not bad - way better than scalar code and probably still quite efficient, depending on the context in which it is used.

Comment: @PaulR: there's another way to left-shift by small values: `pmulld` by powers of two.  We can use `pshufb` to look up the right power of two.  Also, turns out the OP's actual problem was shifting compile-time constant values by small shift counts, so a single pshufb LUT was all that was needed.

Comment: Yes, I see the requirement is now only for shifts up to 4, so that could be a nice alternate solution for this particular case.

Comment: @PeterCordes: FWIW I've added an alternate idea for small shifts (<= 4) as an answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AVX1 doesn't have 256b integer operations, only FP.  So I assume you're really looking for an alternative to `__m128i _mm_srlv_epi32()`.  Using extractf128 / insertf128, you can easily do this for 256b vectors, but it's better to just use more 128b loads/stores, esp. if you have an AVX2 version that can run on CPUs with AVX2 support.  (The existing AVX1-only CPUs all happen to have 128b load/store data paths, so 256b loads/stores are barely an advantage.)

The round trip from vector to scalar is pretty expensive (either store-forwarding stalls when reloading after scalar stores, or a lot of `movd` / `pextrd` / `pinsrd`), so even something pretty clunky might still be better than integer code, depending on whether throughput or latency are more important in the code you're using this in.

**The best idea I have is basically scalar in vector regs: 4 shifts (one for each different shift count) and 3 immediate-blends to combine the results.**

**update**: idea 2: left shift with a 32bit multiply by 2<sup>count</sup>.  See the end of this answer.

If the shift counts aren't compile-time constants, you'll need to unpack the vector of shift counts so you have each shift count as the 64b of a vector.  (The non-variable shift instructions can take their count in a register, but they look at the whole low 64b.  And instead of masking (modulo word size) like scalar shifts, they saturate.

Getting each of the 4 elements of an xmm register isolated in an otherwise-zero destination is tricky.  You can't just byte-shift them down to the bottom, because that would leave non-zero bytes from the second element.

Since this is for AVX without AVX2, I'm assuming you have a separate version for AVX2 CPUs.  So for Intel, this version will be used on SnB/IvB.  This means you have two 128b shuffle units, instead of just one on Haswell and later.

```
## 4 shift-counts in the elements of   xmm0 = [ D C B A ].  element 1 isolated in xmm1, etc.
vpsrlq      xmm2, xmm0, 32           ; xmm2 = [ 0 D 0 B ]
vpunpckhqdq xmm4, xmm2, xmm0         ; xmm4 = [ D C 0 D ]
vpshufd     xmm3, xmm4, 0b01010110   ; xmm3 = [ 0 0 0 C ]
vblendps    xmm1, xmm2, xmm0, 0b0001 ; xmm1 = [ 0 D 0 A ]
; or
vpblendw     xmm1, xmm2, xmm0, 0b00000011 ; xmm1 = [ 0 D 0 A ]
```

`vblendps` runs on p0/5 on SnB/IvB.  The equivalent `vpblendw` runs on p1/p5 on SnB/IvB.  On Haswell/SKL it's p015 vs. p5, so blendps is much better (same choice of ports as `PAND`).  For SnB, maybe use a combo of both for blending the shift results.  With intrinsics, using FP instructions on integer data requires a lot of casting, which makes the source ugly and harder to read.  Unless you're going to tune this to fit best into the surrounding code with perf counters and microbenchmarks, just use `pblendw` *for SnB/IvB*.  Otherwise just cast and use `blendps`.

Alternative if you have a `[ 0  -1  0  -1 ]` mask available, a vector AND can run on more ports, and shorten the dependency chain for `xmm3`.  This is not enough better to justify loading or generating the mask, so prefer the previous version that does it all with shifts/shuffles/blends.

```
vpcmpeqw   xmm5, xmm5,xmm5            ; all-ones
vpsrlq     xmm5, xmm5, 32             ; [ 0 -1  0 -1 ]: generate the mask on the fly if desired

vpand       xmm1, xmm5, xmm0           ; [ 0 C 0 A ]
vpsrlq      xmm2, xmm0, 32             ; [ 0 D 0 B ]
vpunpckhqdq xmm3, xmm1,xmm1            ; [ 0 C 0 C ]  ; saves 1B vs. the equivalent pshufd: no imm8 byte
vpunpckhqdq xmm4, xmm2,xmm2            ; [ 0 D 0 D ]
```

---

Side note: bizarrely, on Skylake, `VPSRLVD ymm,ymm,ymm` is cheaper (1 uop) than `PSRLD xmm,xmm,xmm` (2 uops).  Immediate-count `PSRLD` is only 1 uop, though.  (From [Agner Fog's insn tables](http://agner.org/optimize/)).

@BeeOnRope's testing confirms that Agner's latency numbers are from the data input to the data output, with the shift-count not on the critical path.  Latency from shift-count input to data output is 2c(xmm) or 4c(ymm), as usual for 1c a in-lane broadcast vs. 3c for a lane-crossing broadcast.

---

### uop counts:

#### With scalar code for compile-time-constant shift counts, the whole thing might look like:

```
movaps    [rsp - 16], xmm0
shr       [rsp - 16], 3         ; 3 uops with a memory-destination.  5 uops for variable count with a memory destination
shr       [rsp - 12], 1
shr       [rsp -  8], 4
shr       [rsp -  4], 1
movaps    xmm0, [rsp - 16]      ; store-forwarding stall here from the 4x 32b stores to the 128b load
```

---

Or maybe for variable-count:

```
## data in xmm0,  shift counts in xmm1, results in xmm2
vmovd      eax, xmm0      ; 1 uop
vmovd      ecx, xmm1      ; 1 uop
shr        eax, cl        ; 3 uops because of CISC stupidity
vmovd      xmm2, eax      ; 1 uop

vpextrd    eax, xmm0, 1   ; 2 uops
vpextrd    ecx, xmm1, 1   ; 2 uops
shr        eax, cl        ; 3 uops because of CISC stupidity
vpinsrd    xmm2, eax, 1   ; 2 uops

... repeat twice more, for indices 2 and 3
```

So the all-registers way for variable-count shifts is 6uops + 9uops * 3, total of 33 uops.

---

The memory-destination version is 14 fused-domain uops, since I counted a version that has the shift-counts as compile-time constants.  It would be many more with loading or `pextr`ing counts into ecx, since each variable-count shift is 2 uops more than immediate-count shift.

---

So even though the SSE/AVX version is pretty nasty, it's not that nasty.   The fully-variable vector version is still

- 4 uops to unpack the counts
- 8 uops for the four `vpsrld xmm,xmm` insns
- 3 uops for the `vpblendw` or `vblendps` to merge those results.
- **total = 15 fused-domain uops for the fully variable AVX1**.

So the fully-variable vector version is only as bad as the fully-constant store / scalar shuffle / reload version, and that has a store-forwarding stall in it.

Note that just counting fused-domain uops isn't always the only relevant thing.  Latency may be important, and execution port pressure in the unfused-domain may matter.

---

For comparison:

- Skylake: `vpsrlvd ymm, ymm, ymm` is 1 uop,  1c latency, one per 0.5c throughput.
- Haswell/BDW: `vpsrlvd ymm, ymm, ymm` is 3 uops, 2c latency, one per 2c throughput.

And remember, that's for a 256b vector.  All the counts I've done are for 128b vectors.

On Haswell (instead of SnB/IvB), my SSE version would probably bottleneck on shuffle port throughput.  Latency will be somewhat worse, too, because resource conflicts limit the amount of insn level parallelism it can take advantage of.

---

## Left shift by using SSE4.1 `pmulld` to multiply by powers of two.

On SnB/IvB, SSE4.1 `pmulld` is 1 uop, 5c latency, one per 1c throughput.
On Haswell, it's 2 uops, 10c latency, one per 2c throughput.  (Twice the throughput on Skylake, since its uops can run on p1 as well as p0)

The trick is turning the shift-count into 2<sup>c</sup>.  One way is by using a variable shift.  This is fine if you can reuse the exponentiated vector of 2<sup>c</sup> to shift multiple other vectors, otherwise it's a chicken-and-egg problem.

If the range of shift counts is small (i.e. 0..7), you can use SSSE3 `pshufb` as a LUT to map a vector of counts to a vector of 2^c.  `0` in the low byte of each element has to become `1` (2<sup>0</sup>), but `0` in other bytes has to stay zero.

```
##           1<<8 or higher is 0, in an 8bit element
## xmm5 = _mm_set_epi8(0, 0, ..., 1<<7, ..., 1<<2, 1<<1, 1<<0);
## xmm4 = _mm_set1_epi32(0x000000ff);        
## data in xmm0, shift counts in xmm1
movdqa    xmm2, xmm5           ; avoid this with AVX
pshufb    xmm2, xmm5           ; 2^count
pand      xmm2, xmm4           ; zero all but the low byte in each element
pmulld    xmm0, xmm2           ; data * 2^count
```

Intel SnB/IvB: 3 uops (not counting the movdqa which isn't needed with AVX).  Latency from shift-count to result: 7c.  Latency from shift-data to result: 5c.  Throughput: one per 1c (since all three uops can run on different ports).

With Haswell and later: 5c higher latency.  Penryn/Nehalem also take more uops for `pmulld` than SnB, but not as bad latency as Haswell.

---

The LUT is all zero in the upper 64b, but it's non-trivial to convince a compiler to only store the relevant part and load it with movq.  I won't go into that here.

To handle larger shift counts, we could use multiple LUTs with lookups from `[ D-8  C-8  B-8  A-8 ]` to get values for the 2nd byte of each 32b element, etc. etc.  Note that `C-8` has the sign bit set if `C<8`, and `BLENDVB` merges based on the sign bit being set.  It's expensive, though, so a series of merges might not be better than just using the earlier shift/blend-immediate method.

---

Other than masking the `pshufb` result, you could instead add a vector of `set1_epi32(1)`.  Then the range of indices in the LUT with non-zero bytes would be 1..8, and the padding 0 bytes in the shift-count vector would look up the low element of the LUT (which should be 0).  Doing it this way would make on-the-fly constant generation more feasible:

```
## xmm5 = _mm_set_epi8(0, 0, ..., 1<<7, ..., 1<<2, 1<<1, 1<<0, 0);
## data in xmm0, shift counts in xmm1
pcmpeqw   xmm4,xmm4            ; all-ones

psubd     xmm1, xmm4           ; shift_counts -= -1
movdqa    xmm2, xmm5
pshufb    xmm2, xmm1           ; 2^count
pmulld    xmm0, xmm2           ; data * 2^count
```

No advantage to this, unless you really care about generating a constant on the fly in one fewer insn.  (set1_epi32(0xff) is fast to generate with pcmpeqw / psrld 24, but compilers often only generate on the fly when they can do it in one insn.)

---

#### Update:

The OP clarified in chat that the problem is actually *much* simpler: the data being shifted is a compile-time constant (0xF in particular).  Also, only the low 8 bits of the result are needed.

This makes it trivial to implement with just PSHUFB as a LUT, no multiply needed.  See the previous section of this answer that used pshufb to do `2<<count`.

If you wanted a 32b result, you might generate `[ 0 0 D+8 D | 0 0 C+8 C | ... ]` for use as the control mask.  With the right data in each half of the LUT, that will produce the right two bytes.

Comment: Excellent answer and analysis, shaved off 10ms from a tight loop I had on this. On a side note, what are your favorite resources for looking up things like uops?

Comment: @user1043761: Agner Fog's insn tables.  And his microarch pdf for understanding what the table means (e.g. execution ports, and throughput vs. latency).  See the link in my answer, and the x86 tag wiki.  What kind of % speedup is that over scalar, and how does it compare with the AVX2 insn on Haswell or Skylake?

Comment: I'm bandwidth bound now, so from a wall-clock standpoint the AVX2 and AVX version perform the same for me. If I didn't have a deadline I'd try to isolate meaningful numbers. Thanks for the reference!

Comment: @user1043761: cool, thanks for the feedback you were able to provide on how well this actually performed.  Paul R and I were curious.

Comment: going a step further, the shift amounts are never greater than 4. I wonder if there is additional optimization with that in mind...

Comment: @user1043761: Hrm, for left shifts we can use a multiply (SSE4.1 `pmulld`).  Normally we'd have a chicken-and-egg problem: how to turn a shift-count into 2^count so you can multiply by it?  This could still be a speedup for repeated shifts with the same data (shift a vector of `[1 1 1 1]`).  But with only 5 entries (0-4), we can maybe use a variable-shuffle as a LUT to get a left-shift speedup even for non-reused variable data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109303/discussion-between-user1043761-and-peter-cordes).

Comment: @PeterCordes - regarding your comment about the unusual 1c latency for `pslrd`, it is odd. I had not seen that before and thought it was a mistake since I'd expect any "normal" operation (i.e., producing a result in one register) with 2 uops to have at least a 2 uop latency - one of the uops should depend on the other in that case, and both take one cycle, so it's not clear how you could get less than 2 cycles of latency (unless the core had some weird paths where two uops could work in concert, e.g., forwarding the low-half results when half done, etc - but it doesn't seem to be the case).

Comment: ... of course, for operations that write to two registers, or are otherwise weird, the 2 uops may execute in parallel and there are examples of that (e.g., `cwd`). Also, instructions that take 3 uops may have a latency of 2, since the uop dependency may be a tree (uops 1 and 2 execute in parallel, and uop 3 depends on them), and so on. I didn't find any counter examples in Agner's instruction set tables, _except_ `vpslrd xmm, xmm, xmm` (and the `ymm` variant). So what's up with it?

Comment: It turns out it is exactly what you said. First, my reasoning about 2 uop instructions implying >= 2 latency breaks down a bit with 3-operand instructions. Here, it's not always clear which operand is on the bottom of the uop dependency chain. In the case of `pslrd`, what I found is that the dependency is carried via the 1st source arg (the value to be shifted, so like  `ymm0, ymm0, xmm2`) the latency _is_ 1 cycle like Agner shows. So the actual shift operation must be the second uop, and only takes one cycle. Whatever work the first uop does doesn't depend on it, and goes in parallel.

Comment: On the other hand, if the dependency is via the second source arg (so like ` ymm0, ymm1, xmm0` the latency is fully _4 cycles_, which happens to be exactly what AIDA64 [reports](http://users.atw.hu/instlatx64/GenuineIntel00506E3_Skylake_InstLatX64.txt). So evidently the shift amount undergoes some 3-latency operation (perhaps turning it into a shift mask, which takes 3 cycles due to lane crossing?), and then is consumed by the second uop taking one more cycle.

Comment: @BeeOnRope:  Ahhh, yeah that makes sense.  So it adds 1c of latency to the critical path involving ymm0, but if the shift-count input is the critical path, the instruction adds 4c to the critical path for a cross-lane shuffle + the shift.

Comment: Yeah, and here's the final piece of the puzzle. I was testing the `ymm, ymm, xmm` version of the instruction above, which does take 4c latency though the shift-count `xmm`, which makes sense since it has a cross lane shuffle (from the low word of the xmm shift amount register into whatever 32B register is needed to shift a full ymm reg).

Then, however, I tested the `xmm, xmm, xmm` version, which _shouldn't_ need a cross-lane shuffle, and indeed it only takes 2c latency for a dependency through the shift-count (and 1c for a dep though the shift value, as expected).

Comment: @PeterCordes - and Agner's table doens't really distinguish the cases, showing only `v` rather than separate `xmm` and `ymm` cases, since _usually_ you wouldn't expect there to be a difference for a "non-lane crossing" op like this (and in any case he missed the longer latency path by testing through the 1st source operand). Of course, the lane crossing is hidden :).

Answer (score 2):

Just to throw one other idea in the mix, if the shifts are small (<= 4 in this case) then a sequence of compare/mask/add operations is not too horrendously inefficient and uses only SSE2 instructions:

```
__m128i mm_sllv_4_epi32(__m128i v, __m128i vcount)
{
    const __m128i vone = _mm_set1_epi32(1);
    __m128i vtest, vmask;

    vtest = _mm_set1_epi32(0);
    vmask = _mm_cmpgt_epi32(vcount, vtest);
    v = _mm_add_epi32(v, _mm_and_si128(v, vmask));

    vtest = _mm_add_epi32(vtest, vone);
    vmask = _mm_cmpgt_epi32(vcount, vtest);
    v = _mm_add_epi32(v, _mm_and_si128(v, vmask));

    vtest = _mm_add_epi32(vtest, vone);
    vmask = _mm_cmpgt_epi32(vcount, vtest);
    v = _mm_add_epi32(v, _mm_and_si128(v, vmask));

    vtest = _mm_add_epi32(vtest, vone);
    vmask = _mm_cmpgt_epi32(vcount, vtest);
    v = _mm_add_epi32(v, _mm_and_si128(v, vmask));

    return v;
}
```

Obviously you still need to apply this to each half of your AVX vector.

Comment: Very neat idea, esp if only SSE2 is available.  gcc "optimizes" the adds of `vone` into [loads from constants](https://godbolt.org/g/LZeuGF), leaving a function that's still 12 uops.  So shift counts from 0..4 is just about the upper limit of usability for this idea.  (My shift-and-mask idea is 15uops with SSE4.1, and probably 18 uops with just SSE2, replacing the blends with mask + OR.)

Comment: Thanks - one further thought on this is that if we know anything about the distribution of shift values then it might be worth adding tests in order to "early out" when all shifts are complete, so that e.g. if there are lots of shifts of 1 and 2 and few shifts of 3 or 4 then we might be able to reduce the average cycle count,

Comment: This is actually close to what I had come up with before posting (only using AVX instead and using constants), a kind of 'conditional' shift for each possible shift, and it is faster than scalar, but felt very 'wrong' haha. By far the fastest has ended up being the use of _mm256_shuffle_epi8 as a lookup table, as @PeterCordes showed me, it's faster than my AVX2 version using SLLV... luckily my reduced problem complexity allowed for it.